# Div element change places after effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make these div`s stop changing places after an effect?

```
check out the problem on this fiddle:

    https://jsfiddle.net/d1gxuLn8/1/


Full screen result:

    https://jsfiddle.net/d1gxuLn8/1/embedded/result/
```

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of only referring to it through a link, and give us a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 1):

*Remove line 26* in your javascript file`($(this).css('float', 'left');)`

The ***float left*** is what's causing the *reorder*.

Comment: I want it to be in the left, because I am writing in hebrew

Comment: I'm trying to fix it with the .offset(); function, however without a succes so far